# Data base connection create new or reuse?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a windows service application which polls table for data every 5 sec, would like to know should I create a single connection and reuse it everytime or go for creating new connection everytime after 5 sec to read from database.

Comment: I don't see any downside to reusing, whereas making a new connection each time is bound to affect performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reuse would work best. Make use of the in-built connection pooling feature.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear, when you say, "Create a single connection". I understand that to be create an instance of a connection object.

Then yes, create an instance of a connection when the service starts and dispose it when the service stops.

However, be sure to Open() and Close() the connection each time before and after you use it.

ADO.NET will pool the physical connection to the database so you won't have any performance issue this way.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there are a lot of other applications which are competing for the connection to the same DB, I would reuse the connection. But, you should check the connection state before using it as the connection could have become stale due to some reason e.g. DB restarted, admin killing all the active connections or any other Murphys. If the connection is stale create a new connection and start using it.

Answer (score 0):

declare a static Connection property. In get method, check connection, if connection is not open, connect again.something like this..

```
public static SqlConnection conn
get{
  if(this == null)
  {
      this = new SqlConnection();
  }else{
      if(!this.Open()){
          this.Connect();
      }
  }
}
```

You can use conn now.